# Observations in the environment of R studio but empties dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with precipitation data in R but I had a problem that I cannot solve. I will put here the code to be clearer. I have precipitation data (mm/h) for 47 meteorological stations with minute data, but I need the data hourly and a file with all the stations to then interpolate. The problem is, in this moment, to create that dataframes with the 47 stations, these dataframes must be structured normally by 47  observations and 3 variables.

But the problem is that in the environment I can see that apparently the process is correct, but when I open the dataframe I get surprised because there is only one value as you can see in the image.

[Look the dataframe 071212](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AKUn.png)

This is the code I have used to generate the dataframes.

```
setwd("D:/Escritorio/ohiiunam/estaciones")

temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")

lista = lapply(temp, read.csv)

lista<-data.table::rbindlist(lista)

n_last <- 6                                
lista$id2<- substr(lista$id, nchar(lista$id) - n_last + 1, nchar(lista$id)) 

unicos <- unique(lista$id2)

fun <- function(i) {
  i<-lista %>% select(id, intensidad.mm.h, id2) %>% filter(lista$id2==i) 
}

for (i in unicos) {
  i <- as.data.frame(fun(i))
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). This will make it easy for others to help you by being able to test and verify solutions. These links may be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a slight problem that you've named your data.frames with names that aren't syntactically valid (variable names cannot start with numbers). To work with them, you'll need to surround the name in backticks.

```
View(`071208`)
```

It's not clear how you loaded those data.frames, but it might be better to change that import routine to prefix the names with some character value.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with modifications in the assign function.

```
for (i in unicos) {
  assign(paste0("jul", sep=".", i), data.frame(lista %>%  select(id, id2, intensidad.mm.h) %>% filter (lista$id2==i))) 

  }
```

Thank you for the help.